# Python list slicing not finding input with the 'in' operator

Tags: python, list, file, python-3.x, slice

I am currently doing some homework where I load in two text files each with 200 names in them, into two different lists, one boy names and one girl names (ignore the girl names since I haven't finished up with boy names yet). 
I want to ask the user to enter a name and then show how popular that name is. So I'm using slicing to set the first 50 names on the list as popular and the last 50 names as not popular. However down at the if statement it always goes to the else clause no matter what is entered. There's obviously something wrong with setting the boyList[0-51] to popularBoys however I am not sure what, or how to fix it.

```
def main():
    openBoyFile = open('BoyNames.txt', 'r')
    readBoyNames = openBoyFile.readlines()
    openBoyFile.close()

    boyList = [readBoyNames]

    #remove \n
    index = 0
    while index < len(readBoyNames):
        readBoyNames[index] = readBoyNames[index].rstrip('\n')
        index += 1

    print('Boy names: ', boyList)


    openGirlFile = open('GirlNames.txt', 'r')
    readGirlNames = openGirlFile.readlines()
    openGirlFile.close()

    girlList = [readGirlNames]

    index2 = 0
    while index2 < len(readGirlNames):
        readGirlNames[index2] = readGirlNames[index2].rstrip('\n')
        index2 += 1

    print('')
    print('Girl names: ', girlList)



    popularBoys = boyList[0:51]
    notSoPopularBoys = boyList[52:151]
    totallyNotPopularBoys = boyList[152:200]

    print('')
    boyNameInput = input('Enter a boy name to check how popular it is: ')

    if boyNameInput in popularBoys:
        print('The name entered is among the 50 most popular!')

    elif boyNameInput in notSoPopularBoys:
        print('The name entered is not so pouplar. Among 51 - 150 on the list.')

    elif boyNameInput in totallyNotPopularBoys:
        print('The name entered is not popular at all. Among 151-200 on the list.')

    else:
        print('Not a name on the list.')


main()
```

Comment: From your description, this isn't likely to be your problem but note that the Python slice `[a:b]` returns the elements indexed at `a` up to and including `b-1`, not `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem are these two lines:

```
boyList = [readBoyNames]
girlList = [readGirlNames]
```

`readBoyNames` and `readGirlNames` are already lists. You are creating a list containing another list.
If you change those two lines to

```
boyList= readBoyNames
girlList= readGirlNames
```

it works with no problems.